# iOS naming conventions for buttons/labels etc

Tags: ios, naming-conventions

I am relatively new to app development and I was curious if there was any naming conventions to iOS app dev. I found this guide
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/buttons/ but there not really any naming conventions. If there are no "generally accepted" ones, do you have any you recommend?

What I really struggle with is naming buttons differently for the button name (IBOutlet) vs action (IBAction). (ex. for a sign up button: signUpButton vs signUpButtonTapped).

With the other things like labels or textfields I just put the name and then type after (ex. usernameTextField or infoLabel).

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you can also use didTapSignUpButton, but such things are more like personal/team preferences

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it is better to name variables with an **explanation** and the **type** of item (button, label, imageView etc.)

E.g. `signUpButton, nameLabel`

It is better to name the functions with a **verb** which explains the duty or purpose of it.

E.g. `verifyCredentials(), loadHomePage()`

And I prefer naming the actions with a **verb** in past tense which explains the action.

E.g. `signUpButtonTapped()`

You can also check these pages out:

- [Google - Swift Style Guide](https://google.github.io/swift/)
- [RayWenderlich - Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)